# How to Use Laptop's Bluetooth for Desktop

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, desktop, dongle

I have ds4, laptop and desktop. My problem is Desktop's bluetooth dongle is not enough for ds4 always high ms. Also my desktop is better at games. So I want to use laptop's bluetooth but I want to play it on desktop. Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you playing games through Steam? Steam's in-home streaming should let you run the games on your desktop, but control them on your laptop.

Comment: No my games are unoriginal